# Windows 10 Recovery

Tags: windows, restore

So as of right now, I am planning on dual booting my Windows 10 laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. Before I do so, I want to make sure I can recover Windows in case something goes wrong (and I have terrible luck). My laptop came with Windows 8.1 which i upgraded when Windows 10 was free. If I create a recovery disk (and save the system files) would I be able to revert to Windows 10 if something fails or would I go back to Windows 8.1?

Comment: We are not a windows support site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would recover your current system.

For added peace of mind you can download the Windows 10 installation ISO from Microsoft, and you can take a full system backup -- right-click on Start, Control Panel, System and Security, Back Up And Restore (Windows 7). (Why it's called Backup and Restore (Windows 7) is a mystery; what it does is take a full system backup which can be restored using the installation DVD.)